# How to send JSON object with username and password to REST login webservice in iphone?

Tags: iphone, json, web-services, rest

I have to use JSON object for sending username and password to login REST web service. I have done in android with following code.

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    String responseBody;
                    JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject();

                    try
                    {
                        HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://localhost:8080/MTA/login");
                        jObj.put("email", "user@email.com");
                        jObj.put("password", "password12345");

                        StringEntity se = new StringEntity(jObj.toString());  

                        post.setEntity(se);
                        post.setHeader(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json"));
                        post.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
                        System.out.println("webservice request executing");

                        ResponseHandler responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
                        responseBody = client.execute(post, responseHandler);

                        System.out.println("Response : " + responseBody);
                        /* 
                         * You can work here on your responseBody
                         * if it's a simple String or XML/JSON response
                         */

                    }
                    catch(Exception e)
                    {
                        System.out.println("Exception : " + e);
                    }
```

I have to do same in iOS. How I can do in iOS?

Comment: Please clarify your question, are you want login data retrive or insert in php file.

Comment: if u have difficulty in posting data check asihttprequest framework otherwise if creating json within ur app is the problem there is a library called sbjson

Comment: @vishiphone: I want sent username and password to login web service. Then at web service side it check in database it is write or not and give according to that response.
Plz send me if have anyone have code.

Comment: Ya python I have that code for that wait I will update my code for that from that code you can send username and password to web-service and retrive or check username and password.

Comment: OK I will send my code to you.

Comment: @python if this answer is helpful to you then please tap on arrow of my answer for up its also helpful for other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm working with the Ge.tt API, and in order to log in I'm doing this:

```
NSString *email = @"Some email";
NSString *password = @"Some password"
NSString *apikey = @"some api key";
NSString *loginURL = @"http://open.ge.tt/1/users/login";

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:loginURL];

NSString *JSONString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"{\"apikey\":\"%@\",\"email\":\"%@\",\"password\":\"%@\"}", apikey, email, password];

NSData *JSONBody = [JSONString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSMutableURLRequest *loginRequest = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
loginRequest.HTTPMethod = @"POST";
loginRequest.HTTPBody = JSONBody;

NSOperationQueue *queue = [NSOperationQueue new];

[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:loginRequest 
                                   queue:queue 
                       completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error){

                                        // Manage the response here.

                                        }];
```

Comment: Thank you very much Pherediac. you sent me very good response.

    NSURLResponse *response;
    NSError *err;

    NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:loginRequest returningResponse:&response error:&err];
     NSLog(@"responseData: %@", responseData);
    
    NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"responseData: %@", string);

This is code for getting proper response. once again thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Use this code for your web service if is it work inform us or you have any problem ask me.

```
-(IBAction)Submit
 {


if(([user.text length]==0) || ([password.text length]==0) || ([eMail.text length]==0) || ([contactNo.text length]==0))
{
    UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Alert !!!" message:@"Fill All the Text For Registration!!" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release]; 

}

else 
{
    if([self validateEmailWithString:eMail.text])
    {
        NSString *regestrationString=[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"http://www.somename.com/foldername/login.php?user_name=%@&user_password=%@&user_emailid=%@&user_contactno=%d",user.text,password.text,eMail.text,contactNo.text];
        NSURLRequest *regestrationRequest=[[NSURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:regestrationString]];
        NSURLResponse *regestrationResponce;
        NSError *error;

        NSMutableData *regestrationData=[[NSMutableData alloc]initWithData:[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:regestrationRequest returningResponse:&regestrationResponce error:&error]];
        NSString *dataString=[[NSString alloc]initWithData:regestrationData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"%@",dataString);
        UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Thank You!!!" message:@"Your Registration is completed!!" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];        
        [registrationView setHidden:YES];
    }
    else
    {
        UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:nil message:@"Invalid Email" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release]; 
    }
}



 }

 -(IBAction)login
 {
NSString *regestrationString=[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"http://www.somename.com/foldername/login_table.php?user_name=%@&user_password=%@",userName.text,passWord.text];
NSURLRequest *regestrationRequest=[[NSURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:regestrationString]];
NSURLResponse *regestrationResponce;
NSError *error;

NSMutableData *regestrationData=[[NSMutableData alloc]initWithData:[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:regestrationRequest returningResponse:&regestrationResponce error:&error]];
NSString *dataString=[[NSString alloc]initWithData:regestrationData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@" %@",dataString);

regestrationArray=[[NSArray alloc]init];
regestrationArray=[dataString JSONValue];
if(regestrationArray == NULL)
{
    UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Alert !!!" message:@"Invalid Login" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];        
}

userNameField =(NSString *)[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[regestrationArray objectAtIndex:0]valueForKey:@"user_name"]] ;



userName.text=@"";
passWord.text=@"";


[signInView setHidden:YES];
}
```

login.php have your database insert query and login_table.php have database select query.